# Split URL that contains more than one comma javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, split

Basically I try to split a string of URL that contains more than one Comma, but the result turns out to be like this:

```
{
            "photoUrl": [
                "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTU4MTgxOTQ0Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNDI0Mjk1NDM@._V1_UY100_CR19",
                "0",
                "100",
                "100_AL_.jpg",
                "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTczMTk5MjkwOF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDI0Mjk1NDM@._V1_UY100_CR12",
                "0",
                "100",
                "100_AL_.jpg",
                "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZTFiODA5NWEtM2FhNC00MWEzLTlkYjgtMWMwNzBhYzlkY2U3XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMDM2NDM2MQ@@._V1_UX100_CR0",
                "0",
                "100",
                "100_AL_.jpg"
            ]
        },
```

Here is my code, is there a way to fix it....

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                console.log(data[i].genre[i].genre.split(","));
                New_data.push({ photoUrl: data[i].photo[i].photoUrl.split(",") });
                New_data.push({ genre: data[i].genre[i].genre.split(",") });
            }
```

URL Before splitted:

```
'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTU4MTgxOTQ0Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNDI0Mjk1NDM@._V1_UY100_CR19,0,100,100_AL_.jpg,https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTczMTk5MjkwOF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDI0Mjk1NDM@._V1_UY100_CR12,0,100,100_AL_.jpg,https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZTFiODA5NWEtM2FhNC00MWEzLTlkYjgtMWMwNzBhYzlkY2U3XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMDM2NDM2MQ@@._V1_UX100_CR0,0,100,100_AL_.jpg'
```

Comment: I'm guessing you want the first member of the array to be the part after the `/M/`? If so, use a regular expression to trim the expression before you split it.

Comment: I can imagine how the un-split URL looks like before you split by comma, but what is the desired outcome? So what do you want to achieve?

Comment: What is an example of URL?

Comment: 'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTU4MTgxOTQ0Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNDI0Mjk1NDM@._V1_UY100_CR19,0,100,100_AL_.jpg,https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTczMTk5MjkwOF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDI0Mjk1NDM@._V1_UY100_CR12,0,100,100_AL_.jpg,https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZTFiODA5NWEtM2FhNC00MWEzLTlkYjgtMWMwNzBhYzlkY2U3XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMDM2NDM2MQ@@._V1_UX100_CR0,0,100,100_AL_.jpg'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we know the url starts with `https://` we can check each segment for it and build up url accordingly:

```js
const text = 'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTU4MTgxOTQ0Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNDI0Mjk1NDM@._V1_UY100_CR19,0,100,100_AL_.jpg,https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTczMTk5MjkwOF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDI0Mjk1NDM@._V1_UY100_CR12,0,100,100_AL_.jpg,https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZTFiODA5NWEtM2FhNC00MWEzLTlkYjgtMWMwNzBhYzlkY2U3XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMDM2NDM2MQ@@._V1_UX100_CR0,0,100,100_AL_.jpg';

const res = {photoUrl: []};

const array = text.split(",");
let url = "";
for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
  //if value is does not start with https:// append to current url
  if (array[i].indexOf("https://"))
  {
    url += "," + array[i];
  }
  else
  {
    if (url !== "")
      res.photoUrl.push(url);

    url = array[i];
  }
}

res.photoUrl.push(url);

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:unset!important;overflow:auto!important}
```

Comment: yet it still return the same result as what I did..

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question, somehow I thought it was the expected result...updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

One tactical solution could be to extend the split by `,` to `,http` and re-add the needed `http` later on

```js
const text = 'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTU4MTgxOTQ0Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNDI0Mjk1NDM@._V1_UY100_CR19,0,100,100_AL_.jpg,https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTczMTk5MjkwOF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDI0Mjk1NDM@._V1_UY100_CR12,0,100,100_AL_.jpg,https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZTFiODA5NWEtM2FhNC00MWEzLTlkYjgtMWMwNzBhYzlkY2U3XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMDM2NDM2MQ@@._V1_UX100_CR0,0,100,100_AL_.jpg';

var result = text.split(",http").map(url => {
  if(!url.startsWith("http")) {
    url = "http" + url;
  }
  
  return url;
});

console.log(result);
```